# Android ClipChildren and ClipToPadding doesn't work

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, clipping

I have been struggling for a while with the strange behaviour of android Clipping. I have an activity with a ViewPager and I'm unable to deactivate clipping outside the bounds inside the viewpager. The pager is using a single type of fragment which is divided in two parts: the top part is static and is always visible, the bottom part translated left/right to achieve an animation.

The problem is that the translated part of the fragments are overlapped by the currently active fragments.

Does someone have any idea how to disable clipping?

[image: Fragments in viewpager]

[The problem: the view(marked with blue) is visible just on the left side, on the right it's overlapped by the current fragment / out of view bounds.

[image: The Problem]